# How to populate a dropdown list using an array and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble trying to populate a dropdown list using ´jquery´. I have an array of objects called Newjson, and I'm trying to fill a dropdown list with this data.  NOTE: I've got the data through AJAX, the data was stored in a plain object called `json`, I've manipulated that object in order to reverse it, transforming it into an array of objects.

Some HTML code of the dropdown list that I'm trying to configure:

```
   <div>
        <h2>Lista de Grupos</h2>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="form" value="alunos" />
            <div>
                <label for="IDUnidade">Unidade</label>
                <select id="IDUnidade" name="IDUnidade">
                    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="titulo">Visita</label>
                <select id="titulo" name="titulo">
                    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" 
               value="manage">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here's what I've tried, the javascript code, to be exact:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#IDUnidade').on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
          url: location.href,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).attr('name') +'='+ $(this).val(),

           success: function(json){
           $('#titulo').html('<option value="">Selecione...</option>');

        const reversedKeys = Object.keys(json).reverse();
        const newjson = reversedKeys.map(e => ({[e]: json[e]}) );

                console.log(newjson);


               $('#titulo').populate(newjson, {'keys' : true, 'origin' : 'TOP'});
```

It looks like the `populate()` can not populate a form using an array of objects, it fills the form with just one of the elements of the array.

Anyway, I will appreciate any kind of help that you guys may offer to me. Much thanks.

Comment: `url: location.href,` seems weird; are you sure you're getting the data you expect to get? Also, `.populate()` is not part of jQuery, which plugin are you using?

Comment: what are your bits of advice @ChrisG, I'm new to jquery and javascript programming. I've started to learn web development past month. And yes, I'm getting the exact data that I need.

Comment: From what people told me, `.populate()` is a function in Jquery, a plugin to be exact. Here's a page demonstrating the correct use of the function:

Comment: http://davestewart.io/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html

Comment: Can you show example data and the end result you're looking for? Because that library is really old and I can't get it to work even with a really old jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#IDUnidade').on('change', function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).attr('name') +'='+ $(this).val(),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url: target,
      success: function(d) {
        for (let i=0; i<d.length; i++) {
          $('#titulo').append('<option value="'+d[i].value+'">'+d[i].name+'</option>')
        }
      }
    })
  })
}
```